# Hath or has? Which one is better to use

Tags: archaic-language

Here I am  aware of it, but I am not getting it.

> The sea **hath/has** many thousand sands.

**Hath** and **has** both  seem to be same meaning.

Which one is better to use?

Shall I use hath or has?

Comment: You must use "has." "Hath" is never used in modern English. See these questions and their answers: [Are archaic third person singular forms of verbs useful to English learners?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3281), [Verbs ending in -th](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/477)

Comment: @sumelic - You're right, of course, except I might be tempted to change your "never" to a "rarely." (There are a few exceptions where a learner might see [_hath_ used in a contemporary context](http://onelook.com/?w=hell+hath+no+fury&ls=a)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"hath" is typical of the King James Version (KJV) of the Bible and that was translated some years after 1600. If hath is used today in songs or literature the author consciously wants to create an archaic effect.

1611, Bible (KJV), Luke 19:26:
... unto every one that hath shall be given, and from him that hath not, even that he hath shall be taken away ... https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/hath