# Can we use the verb 'hath' in modern English?

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

I've checked the discussion [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82433/110852) and someone said that this verb must never be used in modern English. I've also looked up and this is the old use of **has** according to OALD. However, I found this sentence using that verb from an English app for learning idioms (it was released on 2019):

> "*He hath a heart AS SOUND AS A BELL and his tongue is the clapper, for
> what his heart thinks his tongue speaks*."

I don't know if the sentence was taken from another resource or it's just the part of the idiom. Originally, the idiom in the sentence (that I took from the app) is the phrase in capital.

Comment: It is a quotation from Shakespear's _Much Ado about Nothing_, written in about 1598. It is early modern English, not modern English. Don't use _hath_ unless you're trying to sound like Shakespeare.

Comment: See also [Hath or has? Which one is better to use?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82433/hath-or-has-which-one-is-better-to-use)

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's the link I provided in my question above. I've read that.

Comment: You could have just passed the first 10 words (or even *less*, maybe) of your cited text to Google, to quickly establish that it's a quote from Shakespeare, ***over 400 years old***. That, plus the fact that you obviously read the comment (quite correctly) saying ***"Hath" is never used in modern English** [except facetiously]* should mean there was no need for you to ask here, or for anyone to post another answer on the same topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers because I didn't think of that. Sometimes it's faster asking questions in this site rather than spending lots of time answering my own question when I can use that time to study something else and leave this question to be answered. I mean, as I said since it's taken from the app I've mentioned, I **was** still doubting whether I can use this verb. Besides, how could you expect a newbie to know everything just because the topic's been discussed? Not everyone is smart! (Including me).

Comment: My apologies. I was obviously a bit tetchy yesterday. *And* carelessly hasty with my closevote, since I hadn't even bothered to read your question properly and take note that you'd already read the earlier question. If having done that you *still* seek clarification, we (by which I mean *me* in particular) should just accept that and try to help. To paraphrase an old saying - if you come here seeking a fish to eat right now, you don't want to be given instructions on where to buy or how to make a fishing rod! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. **Hath** is archaic and is not used in current spoken or written English, unless you are deliberately trying to sound *very* old-fashioned (as in, 400 years out-of-date).